# Link to a parent object

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

I have a couple of nested objects, where A is always a part of B.

May I use the following code to access owner's properties and methods?

```
function A( owner ) {
  this.value = function () { return owner.value() + 1 };
}

function B() {
  this.value = function () { return 1; };
  this.a = new A( this );
}

var b = new B();
alert( b.a.value() );
```

Actually, it works. But I would like to know whether it is correct or not.

Comment: That's fine, at least from the implementation standpoint. Do you have any specific concerns about this approach?

Comment: Thanks. Probably, the only concern is that I just do not understand how is that variable being stored in the instance.

Comment: The other answer briefly explains it, I'll just reiterate. You can consider this as a special syntax. `this.foo` references a field of a new object whose prototype is `A.prototype` if your call site invokes `new A()` (as opposed to just `A()` or `A.call(someObject)`, in which case `this` depends on the way the function is called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider to move the methods declaration from the constructors to the prototypes of the constructors. You will save memory if you have a lot of objects A and B, because in your sample for every object there will be a copy of the method inside of it. Moving a method declaration to the prototype will allow all objects to share a single copy of this method. But you will have to keep a reference to the "owner" in A (now you use closures to keep a reference to it).

Answer (score 1):

> Actually, it works. But I would like to know whether it is correct or
>   not.

It works because you create new instance of parent and access it there:

```
this.a = new A( this );
```

The correct way (for inheritence) is to set child's prototype and constructor:

```
A.prototype = new B();
A.prototype.constructor = A;
```

For more explanation, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719119/why-does-listing-the-actual-constructor-of-a-class-in-javascript-important/7719184#7719184) question.

Comment: Well, I do not need class inheritance there. I need to access properties of parent **object**.

Comment: @mailgpa: Generally when you use the word **parent**, it also means it has child. If you are asking only in terms of nested objects or the way you have done it with no inheritance, then you are doing it fine.